# Rails raw query values along with fields name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

This is my query

```
@pg = ActiveRecord::Base.connection
result = @pg.execute("select sum(col1) AS col1, sum(col2) AS col2 from messages")
```

now

`result.values` gives me `[[val1, val2]]`

`result.fields` gives `[col1, col2]`

is there a way we can get result similar to this ?

```
{col1 => val1, col2 => val2}
```

i looked into many solutions.. no luck :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this**

```
@pg = ActiveRecord::Base.connection
result = @pg.execute("select sum(col1) AS col1, sum(col2) AS col2 from messages").first
```

Comment: awesome.. !! please can u explain.

Comment: @Sachinsrinivasan execute statement will return array of results ie. in hash form. So i am fetching first result array element.

Comment: @Sachinsrinivasan please accept answer and upvote if you found it useful. Thank You